# "this" object is not working for x and y in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

The title says it all. I tried to make the player move using the arrow, but this variable is not working for some reason. I need help! In functions.js, when you click the arrow, the line should move, but it didn't. this.x and this.y returned undefined and NaN.

index.html:

```
<canvas id='canvas' id='canvas'width=500 height=500></canvas>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='functions.js'></script>
<script src='main.js'></script>
```

main.js:

```
var draw = new drawCanvas()
var game = new Game()
var player = new game.Player(250,250)
var move = new player.Move()

document.addEventListener('keydown',arrows,false);

function loop(){
    draw.background('#00FF00')
    draw.drawLine(0,0,player.x,player.y)
    requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop)
```

functions.js:

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
var Characters = 'Images/Characters/'
var Background = 'Images/Background/'

function arrows(e){
    switch(e.which){
        case 37: move.Left(); break;
        case 38: move.Up(); break;
        case 39: move.Right(); break;
        case 40: move.Down(); break;
    }
}

function getImage(path){
    var img = new Image
    img.src = path
    return img
}
function drawCanvas(){
    this.background = function(color='#FFFFFF'){
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.rect(0,0,500,500)
        ctx.fillStyle = color
        ctx.fill()
    }
    this.drawLine = function(x1,y1,x2,y2,color='#000000'){
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo(x1,y1)
        ctx.lineTo(x2,y2)
        ctx.strokeStyle = color
        ctx.stroke()
    }
}
//console.log(this.x,this.y)
function Game(){
    this.sprites = []
    this.Player = function(x,y){
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.Move = function(){
            this.Right = function(){
                this.x = 10
                console.log(this.x,this.y)
            }
            this.Up = function(){
                this.y += 10
                console.log(this.x,this.y)
            }
            this.Left = function(){
                this.x -= 10
                console.log(this.x,this.y)
            }
            this.Down = function(){
                this.y -= 10
                console.log(this.x,this.y)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my theory, this.x and this.y was placed in the wrong place, but I checked online and it was seem placed correctly. what did my code go wrong?

Comment: `player` and `move` are separate objects, so `player.x` and `move.x` don't refer to the same `x`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that good with the this function but I think you need do do

```
game.player.move();
```

because player's var has a "new" in it and I have never seen that code before